# When is the Wysiwig generated when using Craftable PRO?

Tags: laravel

I want to generate a WYSIWYG editor for my text field but am unsure how to do so in Laravel Craftable PRO package. In previous Craftable versions, I could achieve this by naming the column "body" (as described in the documentation: https://getcraftable.com/docs/8.0/explore-generator#form).

However, I can't find this information in the new Craftable PRO documentation (https://docs.craftable.pro/commands/crud-generator-command).

Does anyone know which field names are supported?

I tried using a text field, but it was generated as a textarea. It works when I name the field "body", but I also want to use other names, such as "bio" or "content".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

The supported field names for auto generation are `content`, `body` and `text`. For some reason it is missing from the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to swap the component in your generated code from `<TextArea />` to `<Wysiwyg />`.